# Swift: to call function seems confusing

Tags: swift

I have copied following code snippets from developer site of apple.

1. Following code works as expectation:

   ```
   func greet(day: String) -> String {
       return "Hello Umang, today is \(day)."
   }
   print(greet("Sunday"))
   ```
2. While running following code showing error,

   ```
   func greet(day: String) -> String {
        return "Hello Umang, today is \(day)."
   }
   print(greet(day : "Sunday"))
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   <stdin>:7:12: error: extraneous argument label 'day:' in call
   print(greet(day : "Sunday"))
   ^~~~~~~
   ```

I am novice in Swift programming, I have background in Java. So I am facing problem in understanding.

Please guide me if anything I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because first argument in a method is treated as unnamed parameter. So, you can only use **greet("Sunday")** but if you want your first argument to be a named parameter, you can use the following syntax.

```
func greet(day day: String) -> String {
     return "Hello Umang, today is \(day)."
}
```

Notice, the day is name for the parameter day.

Now, you can use it as,

```
print(greet(day : "Sunday"))
```

Comment: Okay. So according to your answer in swift, first parameter always unnamed and after that we have to mention every parameter with is name.
Thanks